# Use static parent instance with extended instance values

Tags: php, oop, late-static-binding

I have a main class

```
abstract class Database
{
    protected $table;

    public function where(array $params)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function get()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and then I use extended versions of the class:

```
Users extends Database
{
    protected $table = 'users';
}
```

Now, whenever I need to select users, I just use:

```
$db = new Users();
$results = $db->where(['id' => 1])->get();
```

This works fine, but I decided that it would be nice, to make a static shortcut specifically for requests by id, but I'm having problems initializing the class statistically.
I created a method `fetch`, that should set the Id and make the return with the found object.

```
class Database // Had to drop abstract, since self cant be used
{
    protected $table;

    public static function fetch(int $id)
    {
        $self = new self;
        $result = $self->where(['id' => $id])->get();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

But, as I commented, `self` cant be used in abstract, so I had to drop it **and** it creates a new instance without the `table` value, since it's empty in the parent class.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php Just using (misusing in your case) `$self` doesn't make `fetch` static.

Comment: "User" is not a special type of "database". Also, by making an SQL wrapper, you actually make you code less secure. Also, use of static code should be avoided, since it causes tight coupling to be introduced. You probably should look up what [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) is ... ya know, to not embarress the university .

Comment: A user *is not* a database.

Comment: While his class organization may be arguably wrong, the class is actually called `Users`, not user; so it represents at the very least a collection of users, not a specific user instance. And that's besides the point anyway; since it can represent whatever the OP wants, that's a matter of opinion and debate; there is hardly **one** school of thought on class naming and resource naming.

Comment: @yivi that makes it actually even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `static` instead of `self` in the method:

```
public static function fetch(int $id)
{
    $self = new static;
    $result = $self->where(['id' => $id])->get();

    return $result;
}
```

This way you will get the instance of an extended class (e.g. `Users`), but not the one in which method is declared (i.e. `Database`).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to resolve at run-time the class. `self` won't help you. You need to use `static` for that. Read on [late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

```
class Database // Had to drop abstract, since self cant be used
{
    protected $table;

    public static function fetch(int $id)
    {
        $self = new static;
        $result = $self->where(['id' => $id])->get();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Since you were using `self`, on runtime you'd get the original base class (the class where `self` is actually used). By using `static`, you get the class where the code is actually run.